# I am not sure why I am getting this output from my function

Tags: c++

My function is supposed to take the user input of dollars and optionally pennies and convert it into all cents result. But for some reason the number I am getting is bigger than what the math should be producing. This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double NumberOfPennies(int dollars, int pennies = 0)
{
    int totalPennies = 0;
    totalPennies = (dollars * 100) + pennies;
    cout << totalPennies;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    cout << NumberOfPennies(5, 6) << endl; // Should print 506
    cout << NumberOfPennies(4) << endl; // Should print 400
    return 0;
}
```

The output from this is 5060 and 4000. I am confused because 5 times 100 plus 6 should produce 506 like what the comments indicate. I am not sure why 5 times 100 and adding 6 gives the result of 506. Mathmatically I can't see how I am wrong but perhaps there is a reason because of my code?

Comment: you function NumberOfPennies return 0

Comment: and your cout have no endl .. that's why you see the 0 at then end

Comment: @TemaniAfif: `std::endl` isn’t a *solution*! It is a *problem*! (in short because you can’t tell whether it is correctly used or misused, in the latter case creating a substantial performance problem)

Comment: @DietmarKühl i didn't say it's a solution. I just explain that he see a 0 at the end because there is no line return in the cout inside the function

Answer (score 1):

You must think like a computer.

```
cout << NumberOfPennies(5, 6) << endl;
```

instructed the computer to call `NumberOfPennies` and print out the value returned by `NumberOfPennies`.

However inside `NumberOfPennies`, you

```
cout << totalPennies;
```

which prints the commuted number of pennies, 506 in this case, before returning the number 0.

so

1. totalPennies is computed.
2. totalPennies is printed.
3. 0 is returned.
4. 0 is printed.
5. end of line is printed and stream is flushed

output

```
          5060
totalPennies^^return value
```

You have two options that I would consider reasonable:

1. Do all of the printing in `NumberOfPennies` or
2. Return `totalPennies` and do the printing in `main`

My preference is option 2 as it keeps the responsibilities of `NumberOfPennies` restricted to doing exactly one thing: computing the number of pennies. If `NumberOfPennies` does nothing but compute, any function can now call `NumberOfPennies` and do whatever it wants with the result, including print. For example using `NumberOfPennies` in another computation or even as an input to itself:

```
NumberOfPennies(64, NumberOfPennies(3,6));
```

So

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int NumberOfPennies(int dollars, int pennies = 0)
{
    int totalPennies = (dollars * 100) + pennies;
    return  totalPennies;
}

int main()
{
    cout << NumberOfPennies(5, 6) << endl; // Should print 506
    cout << NumberOfPennies(4) << endl; // Should print 400
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the return type of `NumberOfPennies` has been changed to match  `totalPennies` and `total pennies` is no longer initialized to zero since that zero was immediately overwritten with the computed result. That mean we can also go one step further if we want:

```
int NumberOfPennies(int dollars, int pennies = 0)
{
    return (dollars * 100) + pennies;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning the totalPennies from NumberOfPennies (and not printing inside NumberOfPennies). Right now you're printing the correct result in NumberOfPennies (506) and then adding the 0 that you return.

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea why you put penny=0 in the parameter;
Please override the method if there is a need.

Your extra "0" comes from "return 0" in your NumberOfPennies.

In main function , you intended to output the value of NumberOfPennis(5,6), which has a value of 0, that is the reason why you got 5060 rather than 506.

Comment: Why write an extra function? [Stay DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)!

Comment: apparently he/she is a beginner to C++, why not using something that wont confuse you?